# SQL Server 2017 Insert to Temp Table Variable is Very Slow but Not in 2014

Tags: sql-insert, sql-server-2017

I'm upgrading my test database into 2017 developer edition. Now I have a problem with my table value function. the insert into select performance is very very slow for 4000's insert record.

```
declare @dateStart date = '4-Jul-2019'
,@dateEnd date = '4-Jul-2019'

declare @ntnOnDate table
( 
[NTM ID] char(8)
,[NTM Type] char(3) -- Posible Value: NTM, UPR, SOL
,primary key clustered([NTM ID], [NTM Type])
)

declare @finishedNTM table
(
[NTM ID] char(8)
,[NTM Type] char(3)
,Dept char(3)
,[Model Number] char(4)
,[Shoes Type] int
,[Shoes Version] int
,[Size] varchar(5)
,[Pairs] int not null
--, primary key clustered ([NTM ID], [NTM Type],Dept, [Model Number], [Shoes Type], [Shoes Version], [Size])
)   

insert into @ntnOnDate
 --- select statement (Only 16 record) --

insert into @finishedNTM (
[NTM ID]
, [NTM Type]
, Dept
, [Model Number]
, [Shoes Type]
, [Shoes Version]
, [Size]
, pairs
)
select 
a.[TSW ID] as [NTM ID]
,'NTM' as [NTM Type]
,a.[From Department] as [Dept]
,b.[Model Number]
,b.[Shoes Type]
,b.[Shoes Version]
,b.Size
,sum(b.Pairs) as Pairs
from [TSW Master] a
inner join [TSW Details] b
    on a.[TSW ID] = b.[TSW ID]
    and a.Issue = b.Issue
    and a.[From Department] = b.[From Department]
    and a.[To Department] = b.[To Department]
--inner join @ntnOnDate c
--  on a.[TSW ID] = c.[NTM ID]
where a.Executed = 1
    and a.Accepted = 1
    and a.[From Department] <> '210'
    --and c.[NTM Type] = 'NTM'
    and a.[TSW ID] in (select x.[NTM ID] from @ntnOnDate x where x.[NTM Type] = 'NTM')
group by 
a.[TSW ID]
,a.[From Department]
,b.[Model Number]
,b.[Shoes Type]
,b.[Shoes Version]
,b.Size
```

The strange thing is when I use "select top 4462" (The record count by the select statement is 4462) with the select statement, the insert will complete in 2 seconds.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.
A'an

Answer (score 1):

I found myself a sollution to tweak the insert performance. I Change the insert statement into :

```
insert @finishedNTM
select 
a.[NTM ID]
,'NTM' as [NTM Type]
,b.[From Department] as [Dept]
,b.[Model Number]
,b.[Shoes Type]
,b.[Shoes Version]
,b.Size
,b.Pairs
from @ntnOnDate a
inner join (
    select
    a.[TSW ID]
    ,a.[From Department]
    ,b.[Model Number]
    ,b.[Shoes Type]
    ,b.[Shoes Version]
    ,b.Size
    ,sum(b.Pairs) as Pairs
    from [TSW Master]  a
    inner join [TSW Details] b
        on a.[TSW ID] = b.[TSW ID]
        and a.Issue = b.Issue
        and a.[From Department] = b.[From Department]
        and a.[To Department] = b.[To Department]
    where a.Executed = 1
        and a.Accepted = 1
        and a.[From Department] <> '210'
    group by
    a.[TSW ID]
    ,a.[From Department]
    ,b.[Model Number]
    ,b.[Shoes Type]
    ,b.[Shoes Version]
    ,b.Size
)  b
    on a.[NTM ID] = b.[TSW ID]  
where a.[NTM Type] = 'NTM'
```

The SUM agregate is moved inside a statement block than I join the block with the other temporary table.

But I still don't know why this problem happened. The query is fine on SQL Server 2014.

Regards
A'an

Comment: I don't know why there is a difference between 2014 and 2017, but it is best practice to use temp tables instead of table variables when your table variable has many records (e.g. + 100's). SQL Server can produce better statistics from temp tables that table variables.